# How to navigate within a JQM popup

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

This should be simple. I have a popup in JQM that popups up just fine. Within the HTML of the popup there is a hyperlink as in the following:

```
<a href="#def">Definition</a>
```

and later in the popup's HTML:

```
<a name="def">
<h1>The Definition</h1>
...
```

The problem is that when I click on the hyperlinked Definition, instead of repositioning to the part of the file I want. It closes the popup.

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible or I'm having a brain fart.

Comment: Add `data-ajax="false"` to the anchor. ID of target should match hash name in href.

Comment: @Omar ... I tried that in my jsFiddle example but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Kolban try it on a popup with more content.

Comment: @omar In my file the ID is correct. I edited the question to reflect the changed ID. I added data-ajax="false" to the <a> tag and what happens is that it loads the main page (the url is: http://www.examplecom/#def). The good news is that the popup didn't close before the new page loaded.

Comment: please try to setup a fiddle with relevant code to your issue.

Comment: @omar I don't have the time to determine if it's an unwanted interaction and I'm not familiar enough with JS fiddle to quickly set something up. There are a couple of thousand lines of JS code but the popup linkage code is as described as above. That is the minimum code that fails. I need to have a working POC tomorrow morning. I went with the IFRAME suggestion and that works fine. I'll revisit when I have some free time. I'll also take the time to get up to speed on JS fiddle so I can better describe and demonstrate issues.

Answer (score 0):

When a popup is shown, the thinking behind it is that any browser page transition should dispose of the popup.  This may be a link to another web file or a link to a jQuery Mobile page within the existing page.  At a high level, I'm assuming that a popup instance has registered a listener on the browser navigation such that when "any" form of page transition is attempted, it hides itself. I don't think you will be able to perform navigation within the popup.  One possible workaround might be to put your popup content in a separate HTML file and place an iFrame within the popup content body ... but personally, I don't like that notion.

I created a jsFiddle for folks to play with.  I strongly suggest that anyone/everyone posting a question post a jsFiddle (where possible).

[jsFiddle of puzzle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/8rp4pphx/)

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <button id="MyButton" data-ajax="true">Show Popup</button>
    <div data-role="popup" id="MyPopup">
        <div class="ui-content">Hello from my popup
           <a href="#def" data-rel="external" data-ajax="false">Definition</a>
           <a name="def"></a>
           <h1>The Definition</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="def">blah</div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
});


jQuery("#MyButton").on("click", function () {
    jQuery("#MyPopup").popup({
        transition: "slideup"
    }).popup("open");
});
```

Comment: Too complicated. See my comment above.